# algorithm to copy a stack

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Is it possible to copy a stack onto another in C without using any external stack or array?

I know that it can be done using recursion, but are there any other possible solution to do this within mentioned constraints?

Comment: you should specify the term 'stack' here. is it some data structure you know? Because if a stack is a black box, which you can apply `push` and `pop` to, you cannot even duplicate it without freeing it up and then pushing everything back.

Comment: Normally this type of _problems_ are homework, so they should be marked appropriate

Comment: i found this problem online , its not homework.

Comment: Using recursion *is* using an external stack.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible, but it is going to take `O(N^2)`. Consider stacks `S` (source) and `T` (target).

1. init `count` to zero
2. pop the top element `E` off the stack `S`, then push the remaining data onto stack `T`, leaving `count` items on stack `S`
3. push `E` on top of `S`
4. Copy elements back from `T` to `S`
5. increment `count`
6. If count is not equal the number of items on `S`, go back to step 1
7. pop elements of `S` and push onto `T`

Steps 0 through 5 reverse stack `S` in place; step 6 moves it over to `T`, reversing the order and producing a copy of the original. It's a destructive copy, though, because the original stack is now empty.

Comment: no doubt this solution is  correct but O(N*N) time complexity is not desirable.

Comment: I wish I could follow this, any chance we could get a concrete example?

Comment: @PiyushGoyal In computing you can buy some time by giving your algorithm some extra memory, or save memory by making the algorithm do more work.

Comment: @ColinD This should be easy to visualize: take the first item off the stack, move everything else onto the other stack, put the first item at the bottom, and then move everything else back; you get the original stack with the first item at the bottom. Now take the item that was #2 before - it's on the top now - and repeat the process leaving one item at the bottom of the stack; put #2 on top of it, and move things back again. Continue until you've reversed the stack. Now moving it to the target will restore the original order.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, that cleared things up for me immensely.

Comment: I don't understand how `count` being used here? I'm only able to do this for a fixed `Stack` size. I hope someone could help.

Comment: @iMohammad Try doing it manually on a piece of paper with a small stack of three items to get a good feel of how `count` is used.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the steps. we're using 'if statement ' correct? And what does "leaving count items in stack S" ? I already made my code but it does not work for any number of elements.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @iMohammad No, not just an `if`: we're using two nested loops with an `if` inside the outer loop. There will be another loop at the end of this, implementing step 7.

Comment: Hmm .. Im not sure how will I implement these 2 loops. Only way to find out is by testing it tomorrow. This problem is so confusing .  Thanks @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Didn't work out for me. I'm not sure what's my loop condition is. Here's my code for 3 elements stack. hope you can check it. http://pastie.org/5103259

Comment: @iMohammad I think you'll get better help if you post your code in a separate question, link to this answer, and ask for a fix. Comments do not provide enough space for a good answer.

Comment: I ended up using Recursive, since this very costely operation. Thanks @dasblinkenlight for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It's not very efficient, but yes it's do-able.

```
Stack S = source, Stack T = target, int size = number of elements;
while(size >0 ) {
  pop size-1 elements from S (all but last), pushing them onto T (using it as temp storage)
  pop and copy the last element from S; push it back onto S;
  pop and push size-1 elements on T back to S.
  push your copy  of the last element onto T
  decrement size;
}
```

To quote ugoren,  this is similar to the tower of "Hanoi with 2 pegs, plus a constant number of 1-disc storage spaces"

Comment: in hanoi you cannot place a larger disc on top of a smaller one

Comment: @unkulunkulu I know. It helped with my visualization so I left it in there to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll present my own visualization and a solution for a true non-destructive copy from one stack to another.

So we have a pair of stacks `S` and `T`, we can imagine them growing towards each other like this:

```
    ____________        _______________
    |                                  |
S   | S0 S1 S2   ........     T2 T1 T0 | T
    |____________       _______________|
```

If we consider the whole data structure as a single sequence `(S0, S1, S2, ...., T2, T1, T0)`, we can perform actions of moving or copying a  particular element from position `i` to position `j`. How do we do this? We can move through this sequence in small steps like this:

```
void MoveLeft()
{
    T.push( S.pop() );
    curPosition--;
}

void MoveRight()
{
    S.push( T.pop() );
    curPosition++;
}
```

Then we can have access to any element, remember it, then move to any other position and put that element there. Here is the helper function:

```
void MoveToI(int i)
{
    while( curPosition > i ) {
        MoveLeft();
    }

    while( curPosition < i ) {
        MoveRight();
    }
}
```

So using these operations we basically transform the sequence `(S0,S1,S2,...,SN)` to `(S0,S1,S2,...,SN,SN,SN-1,...,S2,S1,S0)`.

And here is the algorithm:

```
curPosition = NElements;
for( int i = 0; i < NElements; ++i ) {
    MoveToI( i );
    x = T.peek();
    MoveToI(Nelements);
    T.push( x );
}

MoveToI( Nelements );
```

Comment: Oh, very clever! Basically, you drop the same item onto `T` once you're done with the move back to `S`, effectively duplicating the thing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, right, but the main point is working with this pair of stacks as a slow step-by-step array, which is much simpler to embrace :D

Answer (score 0):

It’s a O(N) operation because the stack is a continuous region of known beginning and end that can be `memlcpy()` or `memcpy_s()` from one process to shared memory or sent via IPC. Ideally, if this some process replay or live migration code, check that the data structures and ABI are close enough before doing anything. Also, copy the heap. Then, the trick is setting a magic variable somewhere to indicate one process should wait to get ready to run while the other should shutdown. File handles, mutexes, semaphores and other kernel-mode state would need to be copied also. It’s cheaper to either a) use `fork()` which does all of this for you OR b) have a checkpoint-able reactor (stack, heap and external resources) that can “stop the world” pause all threads and restart them all in the child process before killing it. I would fork() + exec() and copy the stack and heap. There will likely need to be an ancillary entry pointers patch table (array of two pointers: old pointer -> new pointer) that will have to patch code, stacks, heaps, constants table in order to not crash.